# Why can't I deploy Flutter JavaScript to firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing `push-notifications` in a `Flutter` project. I want Firebase functions to trigger the notification whenever there is a change in a certain
`collection` in the database.

Using `JavaScript` to write the function.
`Node version: 16`

### To reproduce:

Step 1: `firebase init functions`

Step 2: `? Please select an option: Use an existing project`

Step 3: `? Select a default Firebase project for this  directory: my-project-1 (my-project-1)`

Step 4: `? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? JavaScript`

Step 5: `? Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? Yes`

Step 6: JavaScript code for `index.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

// fcm notification
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
  .document("rooms/{roomId}/")
  .onWrite(async(change, context) => {

    const payload = {
      "notification":{
        "title": "Firebase messaging",
        "body": "A message",
      },
    };
    const options = {};
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice('TOKEN-ID', payload, options);
  });
```

Step 7: `npm run deploy`

When deploying to firebase, this is the error returned:

```
9:34  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1
noname@inoname functions % npm run deploy
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: All modern node versions should be using a JavaScript that understands the arrow operator.

Comment: Then its weird that error

Comment: Instead of just posting the code, post the full instructions you take to reproduce this issue, starting with `firebase init` in a few directory, all the way through the changes you make to it before deployment. We should be able to duplicate the result using the instructions you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked ChatGPT, which provided me this code that somehow works. I can't spot the difference, but now it works:

*Edit: Found out it was the `async` property causing the problem. By removing `async` and `await` it compiled and deployed

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.chatMessageNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("rooms/{roomId}")
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newData = change.after.data();
      const previousData = change.before.data();

      if (newData.updatedAt !== previousData.updatedAt) {
         // Perform your notification sending logic here
         // Use newData and previousData to access the updated and previous document data
         // Send the notification to the desired device token
      }
    });
```

Comment: I mean…. One’s on write and one’s on update, that seems like a difference.